# Particle draw order

Tags: three.js

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix the below issue?
[image]

The red is just a plane (representing water) with a shader material. I have written a custom shader for the water material, but its very simple (I get it to display red). As you can see from the image below the two particle systems seem to mess up the draw order.

Weirdly - if I use a standard THREE material for the water, like phong or lambert, then the issue doesn't happen. Is there some define / property that I need to change on the shader material to prevent this from happening?

Many
Thanks

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing the code. You have experimented with `material.transparent = false` and so on. Right?

Comment: Hi mrdoob, yeah I did. I was able to resolve this but I think its a bit of a problem. I was able to fix it by only adding the particles to the scene last. It turned out that when the particles were added first to the scene this would become a problem. The problem with this is that it only comes out in these complex scenes, so i cant isolate it. Is the order added to the scene meant to affect it?

Comment: I guess the problem is that both objects were/are in the same position?

Comment: Actually they are different. The red plane is at the origin of the world (0,0,0) and the particle system is somewhere else. I don't know if maybe there was a define I did not set though... When I use a MeshPhongMaterial for the plane (instead of a shader material) then it works as expected. I tried depthWrite & depthTest as well as setting a few defines like USE_MAP etc... but I couldn't see how/what was different about using the shader versus the phong <:/

Comment: Could you try setting up a jsfiddle reproducing this?